# SQL DateDiff in Minutes Spanning Over Night

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, time

Trying to get the difference in minutes between a datetime field and a time field.  I'm using the datediff function.

When the start time starts on one date like '2018-01-08 22:35:55.043' and the end time is the following day like '00:35:56.2136644', the result is counting from the end time to the start time.

Examples:

```
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST('2018-01-08 22:35:55.043' AS TIME), '00:35:56.2136644') AS minDiff1
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE,  '00:35:56.2136644', CAST('2018-01-08 22:35:55.043' AS TIME)) AS minDiff2
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(TIME, '2018-01-08 22:35:55.043'), '00:35:56.2136644') AS minDiff3
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:35:56.2136644', CONVERT(TIME, '2018-01-08 22:35:55.043')) AS minDiff4
```

The results were different from what I was expecting.  The desired result would be 120 minutes.

```
minDiff1 = -1320

minDiff2 = 1320

minDiff3 = -1320

minDiff4 = 1320
```

Original Query

```
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(test_start_datetime as TIME), test_end_time) AS minDiff
from user_exam
```

Comment: Convert your time field to a date field - thats the only way to make this reliable.

Comment: it is ambiguous. Where does it say that 00:35:56.2136644 is 2018-01-09 00:35:56.2136644 and not 2018-01-10 00:35:56.2136644 or 2099-01-09 00:35:56.2136644. Store full dates.

Comment: How do you know that a time is in _any_ given day, e.g. from 23:00 to 23:10 might be 13 days and ten minutes? Is there some limit that can be applied, e.g. the interval never exceeds 8 hours so 09:00 to 08:00 is invalid since it would be (a minimum of) 23 hours?

Comment: If you realize it's going over in terms of the day, you obviously need to include the day with the time, which is datetime.  So provide 2 datetimes to the function instead of insisting on time or casting a datetime to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes that the time belongs to the same day or the very next day:

```
SELECT *, CASE
    -- same day -- start time is less than end time
    WHEN CAST(datetimecol AS time) <= timecol THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(datetimecol AS time), timecol)
    -- next day -- start time is more than end time (it rolled over into next day)
    ELSE 1440 - DATEDIFF(MINUTE, timecol, CAST(datetimecol AS time))
END
FROM (VALUES
    (CAST('2018-01-08 22:35:55.043' AS DATETIME), CAST('22:35:55.0433333' AS TIME)),
    (CAST('2018-01-08 22:35:55.043' AS DATETIME), CAST('23:35:56.2136644' AS TIME)),
    (CAST('2018-01-08 22:35:55.043' AS DATETIME), CAST('00:35:56.2136644' AS TIME))
) AS tests(datetimecol, timecol)
```

In the above example 1440 is the number of minutes in 24 hours.

[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e2a566b762a070e98b100b3d043461da)

Answer (score 0):

Let us first reconsider your examples:

```
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST('2018-01-08 22:35:55.043' AS TIME), '00:35:56.2136644') AS minDiff1
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE,  '00:35:56.2136644', CAST('2018-01-08 22:35:55.043' AS TIME)) AS minDiff2
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(TIME, '2018-01-08 22:35:55.043'), '00:35:56.2136644') AS minDiff3
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:35:56.2136644', CONVERT(TIME, '2018-01-08 22:35:55.043')) AS minDiff4
```

Converting/casting from datetime to time throws the date part away. Thus, you are actually running:

```
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '22:35:55.043'', '00:35:56.2136644') AS minDiff1
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE,  '00:35:56.2136644', '22:35:55.043') AS minDiff2
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '22:35:55.043', '00:35:56.2136644') AS minDiff3
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:35:56.2136644'22:35:55.043') AS minDiff4
```

At this point, you seem to not be considering the fact that `DATEDIFF` is directed, meaning it counts (first argument units passed) FROM second argument TO third argument. Thus, since 00:35 is 1320 minutes earlier than 22:35 (of the same day), 00:35 -> 22:35 returns 1320, whereas 22:35 -> 00:35 returns -1320.

---

To be completely precise, since `DATEDIFF` uses datetimes, your times/time-representing strings are implicitly converted to dates. Since a date is not provided by you, the date used is the one with value 0: 1st January 1900. That's the common day the function acts upon.

Comment: thanks for your help - "you seem to not be considering the fact that DATEDIFF is directed"  I saw the pattern but was not able to figure out how to get outside of the literal counting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see 120 that's mean time difference is not enough for your purpose. With your question you want to find difference between 22:35 and following day 00:35
You need to find DATETIME difference something like that:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,         CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME)
                               +CAST(CAST('22:35:55.2136644' AS TIME) AS DATETIME)
                             , 
                                CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME)+1
                               +CAST(CAST('00:35:56.2136644' AS TIME)AS DATETIME)

                ) AS minDiff1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Zeki